# Web application context scope strange behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scope

Using spring on a webservice I have this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testOperation", method = GET)     
public String testOperation() throws Exception 
{                   
    ts.setName("First Value");
    ts.name = "Second Value";
    return ts.getName() + " and " + ts.name;                
}
```

The response received is "First Value and Second Value". I do not understand why is not "Second Value and Second Value". ts is a request scope injected variable. The code is:

```
@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TS implements Serializable{        
    public String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I do not understand this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `TS` is configured to be request scoped obviously spring creates proxy for it. So `setName` and `getName` invocations are redirected to `TS` instance that is created for every request. But direct field reference can't be proxied and it affects only instance injected to controller.